# Как есть альтернатива flex-direction: column-reverse

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть список сообщений, который нужно отобразить снизу вверх. Использовать flex-box не могу. Так как при display: flex перестает отображаться вертикальная прокрутка. 
Каким иным образом, я могу отобразить элементы в нужном мне порядке ?

```
<div class"container">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

То как элементы отображаются, я хочу, отображать их в обратном порядке. `flex-direction: column-revers` позволяет это сделать, но я не могу использовать flexbox в своем случае. Вот и ижу альтернативу. (помимо того, чтобы использовать `.reverse()` на массиве моих объектов.

Comment: код ваш покажите

Comment: Отредактитовал пост.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

извращение)

```css
.container {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.item {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а, по-моему, прикольно :) плюс Вам

Comment: Клевый вариант :)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, всем кто откликнулся, классные варианты. Но пришел к выводу, что в моем случае применить `.reverse()` к массиву с объектами самый простой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность, то можно использовать Grid (хотя и выходит топорно):

```
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.item:first-child {
  order: 5;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}

.item:last-child {
  order: 1;
}
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/b0pLt895/

Comment: Спасибо, но не вариаент :( Прейдется дописывать функционал, и индекс обьекта ставить как order, проще уже с reverse() ^) Я искал вариант похожий на флекс дайрекшн.